# Making sure my SQL query is correct

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-entities

I am trying to run the query below, but somehow I am doing something wrong. I am no expert in SQL Server, but as far as I can see, there is no problem with the code that I am using, but if anyone can see my problem, please point it out to me.

```
INSERT INTO
    [dbo].[StockItems] ([StockCode],[Description],[Mass],[UnitCost],[MinimumStock])
SELECT DISTINCT
    [s].[New_StockCode],
    RTRIM(LTRIM(ISNULL([s].[New_Description], ''))),
    [s].[Mass],
    CAST([s].[ UnitCost ] AS float),
    CAST([s].[Minimum Stock] AS float)
FROM
    [ExcelItemStock].[dbo].[StockItems$] AS [s]
WHERE
    [s].[New_StockCode] NOT IN (
        SELECT
            [StockCode]
        FROM
            [dbo].[StockItems]
        ) AND
    [s].[New_StockCode] IS NOT NULL AND
    [s].[ UnitCost ] IS NOT NULL AND
    [s].[Minimum Stock] IS NOT NULL
```

The errors:

> The select list for the INSERT statement contains fewer items than the
>   insert list. The number of SELECT values must match the number of
>   INSERT columns.
>
> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AND'.

I am using the same amounts of items in both my **INSERT** and **SELECT**. I also cannot see where my problem lies with the **AND** error?

I am using linq-to-entities and here is my class below if it might help in any way:

```
public class StockItem
{
    public StockItem()
    {
        SectionGroups = new HashSet<SectionGroup>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }


    private string _stockCode;
    [Index(IsUnique = true)]
    [StringLength(450)]
    [Required]
    public string StockCode
    {
        get { return _stockCode; }
        set { _stockCode = value.ToUpper(); }
    }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SectionGroup> SectionGroups { get; set; }

    public double? Mass { get; set; }

    public double UnitCost { get; set; }

    public double? MinimumStock { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return StockCode + " - " + Description;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Added the suggested `,` and getting the error:

> Incorrect syntax near 's'.

@Sachu -- Here is a picture to maybe better explain why I am using the `StockItems$`

[image]

I have found my issue! Sorry for wasting all of your time. I forgot to add the extra column to my `dbo.StockItems$` table in my `ExcelItemStock` database. Totally my fault!

Comment: You are missing a comma between the 2 `CAST`

Comment: Do you really have a column  `[ UnitCost ]` with starting and trailing spaces

Comment: @ughai - Yes, it was auto generated from an Excel spreadsheet.

Comment: Which excel provider are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Problem in your SELECT statement:

```
    CAST([s].[ UnitCost ] AS float)
    CAST([s].[Minimum Stock] AS float)
```

Missing a common between these lines

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That did the job, but now I am getting the error: _Incorrect syntax near 's'_. I have also updated the question above with the added `,`

Comment: I see [ UnitCost ]. Have you try remove the space ?

Comment: I did fix the spaces, but I am still getting the same error for some reason?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct except a `,` between last two values

```
CAST([s].[ UnitCost ] AS float),
    CAST([s].[Minimum Stock] AS float)
```

so in `Select` it will consider only `4 values` while in `Insert` you specified `5 columns`

Comment: Thanks for the reply! That did the job, but now I am getting the error: _Incorrect syntax near 's'._ I have also updated the question above with the added `,`

Comment: @caretaker22 does `StockItems$` $ symbol in it?

Comment: can u just run the select statement in sql server and check whether the error is coming?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80765/discussion-between-sachu-and-caretaker22).